# Change format and align the count

Tags: aix, text-formatting

I want to change the format

From:
Sample.txt

```
   Count   Data
   1 C0263/Pre-approved Auto Load BC
   1 C0263/Pre-approved Auto Load BC Holders
   3 C0268/Pre-approved Auto Loan
```

To:
Output.txt

```
   Data                                       Count
   C0263/Pre-approved Auto Load BC            1
   C0263/Pre-approved Auto BC Holders         1
   C0268/Pre-approved Auto Loan               3
```

Comment: So you want to change the format. That's a perfectly reasonable desire. Why don't you change it?

Comment: Isn’t that what Questions are for, @AlexP?

Comment: are there a whitespaces at the begining of each line?

Comment: @JeffSchaller: What question? The original post simply declares that the poster wants to do something. They did not try anything, they did not run into any difficulties.

Comment: Yes sir @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: @JohnChristianDelaCruz, ok, show your `awk --version` output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**awk** solution:

```
awk 'NR==1{ printf "%4s%-44s%s\n",FS,$2,$1; next }
     { f1=$1; sub(/^ *[^ ]+ */,""); printf "%4s%-44s%s\n",FS,$0,f1 }' Sample.txt
```

The output:

```
    Data                                        Count
    C0263/Pre-approved Auto Load BC             1
    C0263/Pre-approved Auto Load BC Holders     1
    C0268/Pre-approved Auto Loan                3
```

Comment: It doesn’t work sir

Comment: @JohnChristianDelaCruz, why did not you post the output of `awk --version` (as was asked) ?

Comment: When applying the script you gave, the output is C0263/Pre-approved only

Comment: @JohnChristianDelaCruz, now, you got my screenshot https://ibb.co/g3ieaw

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input data is in the file `datafile.txt` and you are using a POSIX shell, you can say

```
sed -e 's/^\s*//' -e 's/\s\+/:/' datafile.txt | while IFS=':' read a b; do
  printf '%-30.29s%s\n' "$b" "$a"
done
```

The `sed` command will (1) delete any leading spaces, then (2) replace the first occurrence of one or more spaces with a colon; the result is piped to a `while` loop which reads two fields separated by a colon then prints them nicely.

If the input data comes from a pipe then delete the `datafile.txt` argument and pipe it into `sed`.